# Eclipse RCP, upgrading from x32 to x64 platform: Automatic build still looks for x32 launcher plugin

Tags: 64-bit, eclipse-rcp

I'm upgrading an RCP from x32 to x64.

I'm able to export the product from within Eclipse without any issues but when I try to export it via my automatic build it doesn't work and gives me the following error:

```
Eclipse_3_7_64Bit\plugins\org.eclipse.pde.build_3.7.0.v20111116-2009\scripts\productBuild\productBuild.xml:69: Unable to find plug-in: org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_0.0.0. Please check the error log for more details.
```

As far as I understand the build is looking for the x32 version of the plugin when it should instead look for the x64 version.

I also read [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Building/64bit)  that I should add this

```
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110502
```

Either I did something wrong or it doesn't work.

**This is the command I use to start the build (Works fine for x32 builds):**

```
""%JavaHome%\bin\java" -jar "%ECLIPSE_LOCATION%\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar" -application org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner -f "%BUILD_SOURCE%\com.company.myproduct.rcp.setup\scripts\build.xml""
```

**Note that I search replaced company and product information!**

**Build.xml**

```
<project name="com.mytest.myproduct.rcp.build" default="buildFull">
    <property file="build.properties" />


    <!--
        PDE Build for Company Myproduct

        init step

        Create Build directories and copy all plugins and features
    -->
    <target name="init">
        <property name="resPath" location="${ant.file}/../../resources"/>       
        <mkdir dir="${buildDirectory}" />
        <mkdir dir="${buildDirectory}/plugins" />
        <mkdir dir="${buildDirectory}/features" />
        <!-- Default Plugins -->
        <copy todir="${buildDirectory}/plugins">
            <fileset dir="../..">
                <include name="**" />
                <exclude name="*/bin/" />
                <exclude name="*.feature/**" />
                <exclude name="*.lck" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <!-- Mobile Plugins -->
        <copy todir="${buildDirectory}/plugins">
            <fileset dir="../../../Company_myproduct_mobile">
                <include name="**" />
                <exclude name="*/bin/" />
                <exclude name="*.feature/**" />
                <exclude name="*.lck" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <!-- Features -->
        <copy todir="${buildDirectory}/features">
            <fileset dir="../..">
                <include name="*.feature/**" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>

    <!--
        Start PDE Build
    -->
    <target name="pde-build">
        <java classname="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main" fork="true" failonerror="true">
            <arg value="-application" />
            <arg value="org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner" />
            <arg value="-buildfile" />
            <arg value="${eclipseLocation}/plugins/org.eclipse.pde.build_${pdeBuildPluginVersion}/scripts/productBuild/productBuild.xml" />
            <arg value="-Dtimestamp=${timestamp}" />
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="${eclipseLocation}/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_${equinoxLauncherPluginVersion}.jar" />
            </classpath>
        </java>
    </target>

    <!--
        Clean Build directory
    -->

    <target name="clean">
        <!-- <delete dir="${buildDirectory}" /> -->
    </target>

    <target name="build" depends="clean, init, pde-build" />

    <!-- ================================= 
          target: buildFull              
         ================================= -->
    <target name="buildFull" depends="build" description="Builds until executable version is available">
        <available file="${buildDirectory}/${buildLabel}/${buildId}-${baseos}.${basews}.${basearch}.zip" property="buildZipOK"/>
        <antcall target="unzipBuildOutputAndCopyExe"/>
    </target>

    <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
          target: unzipBuildOutput                      
         - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
    <target name="unzipBuildOutputAndCopyExe" if="buildZipOK">
        <!-- unzip file  -->
         <unzip src="${buildDirectory}/${buildLabel}/${buildId}-${baseos}.${basews}.${basearch}.zip" dest="${buildDirectory}/${buildLabel}/${buildId}-${baseos}.${basews}.${basearch}"/>                    
        <copy file="${resPath}/Company Myproduct.exe_" tofile="${buildDirectory}/${buildLabel}/${buildId}-${baseos}.${basews}.${basearch}/${archivePrefix}/Company Myproduct.exe"></copy>
    </target>

</project>
```

**productBuild.xml**

```
<project name="Build a Product" default="main">

<!-- ===================================================================== -->
<!-- Global properties.  See the build.properties for information on -->
<!-- the properties which callers can control. -->
<!-- ===================================================================== -->
<property name="allElementsFile" value="${eclipse.pdebuild.scripts}/productBuild/allElements.xml"/>
<import file="${eclipse.pdebuild.scripts}/build.xml"/>
<property name="pluginPath" value=""/>
<property name="pluginList" value=""/>
<property name="featureList" value=""/>
<property name="includeLaunchers" value="true"/>
<property name="generatedBuildProperties" value=""/>
<condition property="nestedInclusions" value="true">
    <istrue value="${p2.gathering}" />
</condition>

<!-- ===================================================================== -->
<!-- main entry point to setup, fetch, generate, build etc. Use -->
<!-- the customTargets.xml to modify the build behaviour. -->
<!-- ===================================================================== -->
<target name="main" description="the main build target">    
    <antcall target="preBuild" />
    <antcall target="processRepos"/>
    <antcall target="generateFeature"> <!-- Generate the feature to drive the fetch -->
        <param name="verify" value="false"/>
    </antcall>
    <antcall target="fetch" />
    <antcall target="generateFeature"> <!-- We are calling generate feature a second time so that we can get the pack / unpack clause fixed -->
        <param name="verify" value="true"/>
    </antcall> 
    <antcall target="generate" /> 
    <antcall target="process" /> 
    <antcall target="assemble" />
    <antcall target="package" />
    <antcall target="postBuild" />
</target>

<!-- ===================================================================== -->
<!-- Generate a container feature based on the product file                -->
<!-- The plugin or feature containing the .product file will need to exist -->
<!-- already, use preSetup or postSetup to fetch it if necessary           -->
<!-- ===================================================================== -->
<target name="generateFeature">
    <eclipse.generateFeature
        featureId="org.eclipse.pde.build.container.feature"
        buildDirectory="${buildDirectory}"
        baseLocation="${baseLocation}"
        productFile="${product}"
        verify="${verify}"
        pluginPath="${transformedRepoLocation}${path.separator}${pluginPath}"
        configInfo="${configs}"
        pluginList="${pluginList}"
        featureList="${featureList}"
        includeLaunchers="${includeLaunchers}"
        buildPropertiesFile="${generatedBuildProperties}"
        nestedInclusions="${nestedInclusions}"
        filterP2Base="${filterP2Base}"
    />
</target>


</project>
```

**allElements.xml**

```
<project name="Product Build allElements Delegator">
    <property name="defaultAssemblyEnabled" value="true" />
    <property name="archiveNamePrefix" value="${buildId}"/>

    <!-- ===================================================================== -->
    <!-- Run a given ${target} on all elements being built                     -->
    <!-- Add on <ant> task for each top level element being built.             -->
    <!-- ===================================================================== -->
    <target name="allElementsDelegator">
        <ant antfile="${genericTargets}" target="${target}">
            <property name="type" value="feature" />
            <property name="id" value="org.eclipse.pde.build.container.feature" />
        </ant>
    </target>

    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <!--  The default assemble target, this will be called to assemble each     -->  
    <!--  config if a custom assemble target is not defined.                    -->
    <!-- The following properties will be defined:                              -->
    <!--        config : The configuration being assembled eg "win32.win32.x86" -->
    <!--        element: The element being assembled eg "org.eclipse.sdk"       -->
    <!--        assembleScriptName: The assemble script to be called            -->
    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <target name="defaultAssemble">
        <ant antfile="${assembleScriptName}" dir="${buildDirectory}">           
            <property name="archiveName" value="${archiveNamePrefix}-${config}.zip"/>
        </ant>
    </target>   

    <!-- ===================================================================== -->
    <!-- Targets to assemble the built elements for particular configurations  -->
    <!-- These generally call the generated assemble scripts (named in         -->
    <!-- ${assembleScriptName}) but may also add pre and post processing       -->
    <!-- Add one target for each root element and each configuration           -->
    <!-- ===================================================================== -->
    <target name="assemble.org.eclipse.pde.build.container.feature">
        <ant antfile="${assembleScriptName}" dir="${buildDirectory}">
            <property name="archiveName" value="${archiveNamePrefix}.zip"/>
        </ant>
    </target>

    <property name="assemble.org.eclipse.pde.build.container.feature.win32.win32.x86" value="true" />
    <target name="assemble.org.eclipse.pde.build.container.feature.win32.win32.x86">
        <ant antfile="${assembleScriptName}" dir="${buildDirectory}">           
            <property name="archiveName" value="${archiveNamePrefix}-win32.win32.x86.zip"/>
        </ant>
    </target>

    <property name="assemble.org.eclipse.pde.build.container.feature.win32.win32.x86_64" value="true" />
    <target name="assemble.org.eclipse.pde.build.container.feature.win32.win32.x86_64">
        <ant antfile="${assembleScriptName}" dir="${buildDirectory}">           
            <property name="archiveName" value="${archiveNamePrefix}-win32.win32.x86_64.zip"/>
        </ant>
    </target>

    <property name="assemble.org.eclipse.pde.build.container.feature.linux.gtk.ppc" value="true" />
    <target name="assemble.org.eclipse.pde.build.container.feature.linux.gtk.ppc">
        <ant antfile="${assembleScriptName}" dir="${buildDirectory}">           
            <property name="archiveName" value="${archiveNamePrefix}-linux.gtk.ppc.zip"/>
        </ant>
    </target>

    <property name="assemble.org.eclipse.pde.build.container.feature.linux.gtk.x86" value="true" />
    <target name="assemble.org.eclipse.pde.build.container.feature.linux.gtk.x86">
        <ant antfile="${assembleScriptName}" dir="${buildDirectory}">           
            <property name="archiveName" value="${archiveNamePrefix}-linux.gtk.x86.zip"/>
        </ant>
    </target>

    <property name="assemble.org.eclipse.pde.build.container.feature.linux.gtk.x86_64" value="true" />
    <target name="assemble.org.eclipse.pde.build.container.feature.linux.gtk.x86_64">
        <ant antfile="${assembleScriptName}" dir="${buildDirectory}">           
            <property name="archiveName" value="${archiveNamePrefix}-linux.gtk.x86_64.zip"/>
        </ant>
    </target>

    <property name="assemble.org.eclipse.pde.build.container.feature.linux.motif.x86" value="true" />
    <target name="assemble.org.eclipse.pde.build.container.feature.linux.motif.x86">
        <ant antfile="${assembleScriptName}" dir="${buildDirectory}">           
            <property name="archiveName" value="${archiveNamePrefix}-linux.motif.x86.zip"/>
        </ant>
    </target>

    <property name="assemble.org.eclipse.pde.build.container.feature.solaris.motif.sparc" value="true" />
    <target name="assemble.org.eclipse.pde.build.container.feature.solaris.motif.sparc">
        <ant antfile="${assembleScriptName}" dir="${buildDirectory}">           
            <property name="archiveName" value="${archiveNamePrefix}-solaris.motif.sparc.zip"/>
        </ant>
    </target>

    <property name="assemble.org.eclipse.pde.build.container.feature.solaris.gtk.sparc" value="true" />
    <target name="assemble.org.eclipse.pde.build.container.feature.solaris.gtk.sparc">
        <ant antfile="${assembleScriptName}" dir="${buildDirectory}">           
            <property name="archiveName" value="${archiveNamePrefix}-solaris.gtk.sparc.zip"/>
        </ant>
    </target>

    <property name="assemble.org.eclipse.pde.build.container.feature.aix.motif.ppc" value="true" />
    <target name="assemble.org.eclipse.pde.build.container.feature.aix.motif.ppc">
        <ant antfile="${assembleScriptName}" dir="${buildDirectory}">           
            <property name="archiveName" value="${archiveNamePrefix}-aix.motif.ppc.zip"/>
        </ant>
    </target>

    <property name="assemble.org.eclipse.pde.build.container.feature.hpux.motif.PA_RISC" value="true" />
    <target name="assemble.org.eclipse.pde.build.container.feature.hpux.motif.PA_RISC">
        <ant antfile="${assembleScriptName}" dir="${buildDirectory}">           
            <property name="archiveName" value="${archiveNamePrefix}-hpux.motif.PA_RISC.zip"/>
        </ant>
    </target>

    <property name="assemble.org.eclipse.pde.build.container.feature.macosx.carbon.ppc" value="true" />
    <target name="assemble.org.eclipse.pde.build.container.feature.macosx.carbon.ppc">
        <ant antfile="${assembleScriptName}" dir="${buildDirectory}">           
            <property name="archiveName" value="${archiveNamePrefix}-macosx.carbon.ppc.zip"/>
        </ant>
    </target>

    <property name="assemble.org.eclipse.pde.build.container.feature.macosx.carbon.x86" value="true" />
    <target name="assemble.org.eclipse.pde.build.container.feature.macosx.carbon.x86">
        <ant antfile="${assembleScriptName}" dir="${buildDirectory}">           
            <property name="archiveName" value="${archiveNamePrefix}-macosx.carbon.x86.zip"/>
        </ant>
    </target>

    <property name="assemble.org.eclipse.pde.build.container.feature.group.group.group" value="true" />
    <target name="assemble.org.eclipse.pde.build.container.feature.group.group.group">
        <ant antfile="${assembleScriptName}" dir="${buildDirectory}">           
            <property name="archiveName" value="${archiveNamePrefix}-group.zip"/>
        </ant>
    </target>
</project>
```

**build.properties**

```
# Version of org.ecilpse.pdebuild
pdeBuildPluginVersion=3.7.0.v20111116-2009


# Version of org.eclipse.equinox.launcher
equinoxLauncherPluginVersion=1.2.0.v20110502

# ProductVersion
productVersion=00.00Test0

############# BASE LOCATION #########################
#
# Specify the directory of the base under which your
# your build target is located. This directory should
# contain the RCP Runtime Binary that you want to 
# compile against.
#
#####################################################

base=//server/Eclipse/Eclipse_3_7_64Bit

############# ECLIPSE LOCATION ######################
#
# Specify the directory of the Eclipse installation
# that will be used to execute PDE Build.
#
#####################################################

eclipseLocation=//server/Eclipse/Eclipse_3_7_64Bit

############# PRODUCT/PACKAGING CONTROL #############
product=/ com.mytest.myproduct.rcp/myProduct.product
runPackager=false

#Set the name of the archive that will result from the product build.
#archiveNamePrefix=

# The prefix that will be used in the generated archive.
archivePrefix=MyProduct

# The location underwhich all of the build output will be collected.
collectingFolder=${archivePrefix}

# The list of {os, ws, arch} configurations to build.  This 
# value is a '&' separated list of ',' separate triples.  For example, 
#     configs=win32,win32,x86 & linux,motif,x86
# By default the value is *,*,*
#configs = *, *, *
configs=win32,win32,x86_64
##& \
#   linux, gtk, ppc &\
# linux, gtk, x86 & \
#   linux, gtk, x86_64 & \
#   linux, motif, x86 & \
#   solaris, motif, sparc & \
#   solaris, gtk, sparc & \
#   aix, motif, ppc & \
#   hpux, motif, PA_RISC & \
#   macosx, carbon, ppc

# By default PDE creates one archive (result) per entry listed in the configs property.
# Setting this value to try will cause PDE to only create one output containing all 
# artifacts for all the platforms listed in the configs property.
#groupConfigurations=true

#The format of the archive. By default a zip is created using antZip.
#The list can only contain the configuration for which the desired format is different than zip.
#archivesFormat=win32, win32, x86 - antZip& \
#   linux, gtk, ppc - antZip &\
#    linux, gtk, x86 - antZip& \
#   linux, gtk, x86_64 - antZip& \
# linux, motif, x86 - antZip& \
#   solaris, motif, sparc - antZip& \
#   solaris, gtk, sparc - antZip& \
#   aix, motif, ppc - antZip& \
#   hpux, motif, PA_RISC - antZip& \
#   macosx, carbon, ppc - antZip

#Set to true if you want the output to be ready for an update jar (no site.xml generated)
#outputUpdateJars = false

#Set to true for Jnlp generation
#codebase should be a URL that will be used as the root of all relative URLs in the output.
#generateJnlp=false
#jnlp.codebase=<codebase url>
#jnlp.j2se=<j2se version>
#jnlp.locale=<a locale>
#jnlp.generateOfflineAllowed=true or false generate <offlineAllowed/> attribute in the generated features
#jnlp.configs=${configs}            #uncomment to filter the content of the generated jnlp files based on the configuration being built

#Set to true if you want to sign jars
#signJars=false
#sign.alias=<alias>
#sign.keystore=<keystore location>
#sign.storepass=<keystore password>

#Arguments to send to the zip executable
zipargs=

#Arguments to send to the tar executable
tarargs=

#Control the creation of a file containing the version included in each configuration - on by default 
generateVersionsLists=false

############## BUILD NAMING CONTROL ################
# The directory into which the build elements are fetched and where
# the build takes place.
buildDirectory=D:/ccviews/.MyProduct2_CR_0065098_Dev/Java/build_00.00Test0

# Type of build.  Used in naming the build output.  Typically this value is
# one of I, N, M, S, ...
buildType=R

# ID of the build.  Used in naming the build output.
buildId=MyProductbuild

# Label for the build.  Used in naming the build output
buildLabel=build_output

# Timestamp for the build.  Used in naming the build output
timestamp=007

#The value to be used for the qualifier of a plugin or feature when you want to override the value computed by pde.
#The value will only be applied to plugin or features indicating build.properties, qualifier = context 
#forceContextQualifier=Testi

#Enable / disable the generation of a suffix for the features that use .qualifier. 
#The generated suffix is computed according to the content of the feature   
#generateFeatureVersionSuffix=true

############# BASE CONTROL #############
# Settings for the base Eclipse components and Java class libraries 
# against which you are building.
# Base location for anything the build needs to compile against.  For example,
# in most RCP app or a plug-in,  the baseLocation should be the location of a previously
# installed Eclipse against which the application or plug-in code will be compiled and the RCP delta pack.

baseLocation=${eclipseLocation}
#Os/Ws/Arch/nl of the eclipse specified by baseLocation
baseos=win32
basews=win32
basearch=x86

#this property indicates whether you want the set of plug-ins and features to be considered during the build to be limited to the ones reachable from the features / plugins being built
filteredDependencyCheck=false

#pluginPath is a list of locations in which to find plugins and features.  This list is separated by the platform file separator (; or :)
#a location is one of:  
#- the location of the jar or folder that is the plugin or feature : /path/to/foo.jar or /path/to/foo
#- a directory that contains a /plugins or /features subdirectory
#- the location of a feature.xml, or for 2.1 style plugins, the plugin.xml or fragment.xml
#pluginPath=

skipBase=true
eclipseURL=<url for eclipse download site>
eclipseBuildId=<Id of Eclipse build to get>
eclipseBaseURL=${eclipseURL}/eclipse-platform-${eclipseBuildId}-win32.zip


############# MAP FILE CONTROL ################
# This section defines CVS tags to use when fetching the map files from the repository.
# If you want to fetch the map file from repository / location, change the getMapFiles target in the customTargets.xml

skipMaps=true
mapsRepo=:pserver:anonymous@example.com/path/to/repo
mapsRoot=path/to/maps
mapsCheckoutTag=HEAD

#tagMaps=true
mapsTagTag=v${buildId}


############ REPOSITORY CONTROL ###############
# This section defines properties parameterizing the repositories where plugins, fragments
# bundles and features are being obtained from. 

# The tags to use when fetching elements to build.
# By default thebuilder will use whatever is in the maps.  
# This value takes the form of a comma separated list of repository identifier (like used in the map files) and the 
# overriding value
# For example fetchTag=CVS=HEAD, SVN=v20050101
# fetchTag=HEAD
skipFetch=true


############# JAVA COMPILER OPTIONS ##############
# The location of the Java jars to compile against.  Typically the rt.jar for your JDK/JRE
#bootclasspath=${java.home}/lib/rt.jar

# specific JRE locations to compile against. These values are used to compile bundles specifying a 
# Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment. Uncomment and set values for environments that you support
#CDC-1.0/Foundation-1.0= /path/to/rt.jar
#CDC-1.1/Foundation-1.1=
#OSGi/Minimum-1.0=
#OSGi/Minimum-1.1=
#JRE-1.1=
#J2SE-1.2=
#J2SE-1.3=
#J2SE-1.4=
#J2SE-1.5=
#JavaSE-1.6=
#PersonalJava-1.1=
#PersonalJava-1.2=
#CDC-1.0/PersonalBasis-1.0=
#CDC-1.0/PersonalJava-1.0=
#CDC-1.1/PersonalBasis-1.1=
#CDC-1.1/PersonalJava-1.1=

# Specify the output format of the compiler log when eclipse jdt is used
logExtension=.log

# Whether or not to include debug info in the output jars
javacDebugInfo=false 

# Whether or not to fail the build if there are compiler errors
javacFailOnError=true

# Enable or disable verbose mode of the compiler
javacVerbose=true

# Extra arguments for the compiler. These are specific to the java compiler being used.
#compilerArg=

# Default value for the version of the source code. This value is used when compiling plug-ins that do not set the Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment or set javacSource in build.properties
javacSource=1.6

# Default value for the version of the byte code targeted. This value is used when compiling plug-ins that do not set the Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment or set javacTarget in build.properties.
javacTarget=1.6
```

Comment: Have you updated the build configuration to tell it you want a 64 bit build? There are numerous other plugins that are different for 64 bit so you need a complete 64 bit build.

Comment: This is my issue. I have no idea what files to change. I have encountered multiple "build" files so far but I'm left confused. Also I can export it without issues from within eclipse! I added some info from the build.xml file.

Comment: There are several 'automatic builds' it is not clear which one this is. One build uses a properties file often called 'build.properties'. Exporting from within Eclipse uses different code.

Comment: I have a 'build.properties' file. I guess its this entry: #configs = *, *, *
configs=win32, win32, x86

Comment: If it has a 'configs=' line that is the one. Show us the file.

Comment: configs=win32, win32, x86

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
configs=win32, win32, x86
```

in your build properties specifies a Windows 32 bit build ('x86' means 32 bit).

Use

```
configs=win32, win32, x86_64
```

for 64 bit ('x86_64').

You will also need to specify a 64 bit Eclipse in the configuration.

Comment: This was definitly one of the pitfalls but I still have the same issues as stated in my opening post. And yes I'm building with a 64Bit Eclipse.

Comment: You need to show us **all** of the build properties and what you are using to start the build running.

Comment: Hello greg! I tried to add all necessary build files. If anything is missing let me know and I'll be happy to provide it.

Comment: Okay you called it right from the start! There was another internal build script that was resetting the config entry back to the x32 version all the time. Thanks for your help again!